# How do I batch convert from Slim to Haml or ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, slim-lang

I have a bunch of Slim files left over from another developer but I find Haml more comfortable. How do I go around doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert your Slim files to ERB by running this in your terminal. It loops through all the `.slim` files and saves their results in `.html.erb` and deletes the original ([please use git](https://hackernoon.com/please-use-git-da3bea7d1234)):

```
for i in **/*.slim; do
    [ -f "$i" ] || break
    echo "Processing file $i"
    slimrb -e "$i" "${i%.slim}.html.erb"
    rm -rf "$i"
done
```

Then convert them to Haml using Haml Rails' `rake task`

Comment: For future searchers, I wonder if you might add some more description of what that code is doing and what "convert them to rails like usual" entails/means?

Comment: Thanks @jvillian. I just copied this off my editor after I made this because no one else did this before. I'll edit this for clarity.